# Wildcard in variable, Shell bash, how to do ? Variable=$variable2*

Tags: bash, shell, variables, wildcard

For me it worked:

```
diretorio=$(echo 'test 123'*)
```

but not worked when i used variable in quotes

```
Var2="test 123" 
diretorio=$(echo '$Var2'*)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Sorry - it's not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: why on earth are you putting a concatenated list of filenames into a variable in the first place?

Comment: Another interesting mess: `a="*"; echo $a; a="'*'"; echo $a` -- no easy way to disable wildcard expansion without introducing other issues, think `if [ -n "$1" ]; then a="-name $1";fi; find /dir $a` (Arrays also works for that case...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest an alternate approach? Instead of making a space-separated list of filenames (which will cause horrible confusion if any of the filenames contain spaces, e.g. "test 123"), use an array:

```
diretorio=("${Var2}"*)
doSomethingWithAllFiles "${diretorio[@]}"
for umDiretorio in "${diretorio[@]}"; do
    doSomethingWithASingleFile "$umDiretorio"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

The mistake in your [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) is that

```
diretorio=$(echo '$Var2'*)
```

is a shot in `/dev/null`, because the *shell* don't expand variables in single quotes.

So :

```
diretorio=$(echo "$Var2"*)
```

Learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
diretorio=$(echo "$Var2"*)
```

Single ones prevent variable substitution

Comment: @sputnick indeed, although not yet propagated to my browser when I was writing my reply.